# Discord.py bot, assign role when a user adds reaction

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot that i saw from this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgCJG8kkq50&t)
Here's the code I wrote

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  message_id = payload.message_id
  if message_id == [message id]:
    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g :g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
    
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)

    if role is not None:
      member_user = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.member.id, guild.members)
      if member_user is not None:
        await member_user.add_roles(role)
        print("Done")
      else:
        print("Member not Found")
        print(member_user)
    else:
      print("Role not Found")
```

But every time I react, the console gives me Member not Found and a None for the user ID.
Am I doing something wrong with getting the user ID? Or is the problem somewhere else entirely?

First time coding anything in python btw. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `guild.members` if you haven't set up your `Intents` correctly, and seeing as you're following an out-dated YouTube tutorial I assume you haven't.

When creating your `commands.Bot` instance, pass in intents, and enable the `members` intent:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=..., intents=intents)
```

Afterwards, enable them on your bot's dashboard. Info on how to do that is in the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents

Comment: Thanks you comment really helped

I was unsure about the command prefix and all but after going thru some documentation i was able to get it to run with this

```intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Comment: Ah well you didn't have `discord.Client` or `commands.Bot` anywhere in your post so I just assumed it was a `Bot`, but the solution is the same for both of them so it works either way.

Answer (score 0):

We have done it like this to asign users a role based on the reaction they give to the welcome message. You can try it and see if it works for your case as well

```
    @bot.event
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
        guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        rolesDict = {role.name : role for role in guild.roles}
        member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
        user = bot.get_user(payload.user_id)
        if(payload.message_id == 769218692948295721):
            for roleName in ["Role1", "Role2", "Role3"]:
                await member.remove_roles(rolesDict.get(roleName))
                
            if(str(payload.emoji) == "\U0001F986"):
                role = rolesDict.get("Role1")
                await member.add_roles(role)
            elif(str(payload.emoji) == ""):
                role = rolesDict.get("Role2")
                await member.add_roles(role)
            elif(str(payload.emoji) == ""):
                role = rolesDict.get("Role3")
                await member.add_roles(role)
```